# Error "open:No error apparent state:unit 68" when reading a file in g77

Tags: fortran, g77

I am trying to read data from a file and I have received the following error

```
c:/work/readdata.exe
open:No error
apparent state:unit 68 named data 1108.prn
lately writing direct unformatted external IO

abnormal program termination
```

Is anyone familiar with this type of error? I am using g77.

Comment: for starters "writing direct unformatted external" seems to mean you are writing, not reading.  Show the code (relevent `open` and `read` statements )

Comment: Welcome. Please show the code! It is completely necessary, read [mcve]. Also take the [Tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Firstly please stop using g77. g77 is dead, and hasn't been supported in well over a decade. Gfortran is what you should be using.

Comment: "Error"??? it looks more like the IO from the program. Do you a file named 1108.prn anywhere?